# SQL Server Full Text Search to find containing characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I have a table with a column `Document` that is FullText Index.
Let say I have this in this table:

```
| ID | Document                    |
| 1  | WINTER  SUMMER SPRING OTHER |
```

My requirement is to find rows that contains 'ER'.

For this I am querying like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 
    [FullTextSearch].[Document], [FullTextSearch].[ID]
FROM 
    [FullTextSearch] 
WHERE  
    CONTAINS(Document, '"*ER*"')
```

But this is not working.

Please suggest what should be best way to do this using FullTextSearch.

I am expecting id 1 should be returned.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. That query is product specific.

Comment: @jarlh Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: what is your expected result? I don't understand your table structure.

Comment: Take a look to this article to see how the contains works in FTS: https://csharpvault.com/blog/sql-server-full-text-search/

Answer (score 0):

You can user LIKE operator to find the value.

The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.

There are two wildcards used in conjunction with the LIKE operator:

% - The percent sign represents zero, one, or multiple characters
_ - The underscore represents a single character

Syntax,

SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE columnN LIKE pattern;

This query can help to find the result.

SELECT Document,ID FROM FullTextSearch
WHERE Document LIKE '%ER%';

Answer (score -1):

It's a wildcard query...This should work.

```
 SELECT TOP 100 
[FullTextSearch].[Document], [FullTextSearch].[ID]
FROM 
[FullTextSearch] 
WHERE  
Document like '%ER%'
```

========OR=============

```
   SELECT TOP 100 
        [FullTextSearch].[Document], [FullTextSearch].[ID]
    FROM 
    [FullTextSearch] 
    WHERE  
    CONTAINS(Document, '%ER%')
```